# Suppose that $P[|X| \geq \lambda ] \leq Ce^{-c\lambda^{2}}$ then $E[e^{c'|X|^{2}}] \leq C'$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The following assertion was made in Terry Tao's book on random matrix theory:
Let $X$ be a real valued random variable

> Suppose that $P[|X| \geq \lambda ]  \leq Ce^{-c\lambda^{2}}$ then $E[e^{c'|X|^{2}}] \leq C'$

where $c,c',C,C'$ are positive real numbers.

I was having trouble actually verifying this and was looking for some help in doing so.

Comment: I assume you are allowed to choose $c$ and $C$ are given and then $c',C'$ are allowed to be chosen dependent on $c$ and $C$?

Comment: These are two equivalent characterizations of sub-Gaussian random variables. See [Proposition 2.5.2 of Vershynin's book](https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf#page=33) for a proof.

Comment: Mathematics is about rigor and precision. If you quote, quote *all relevant parts*, please. If that book *really* says so, you should burn it, and dissolve the ashes in acid. I suspect it contains $c'<c$ in that "where" clause, though.

Comment: @angryavian Thanks, I'll take a look and see, if I can understand it, I'll write it up.

Comment: @RhysSteele Yes, I read it as $c,C$ being given and $c',C'$ being dependent respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layer cake formula gives

\begin{align*}
E[e^{c'|X|^2}] &= \int_0^\infty P(e^{c'|X|^2} \ge \lambda)d\lambda \\
&= \int_0^\infty P\left(|X| \ge \sqrt{\frac{1}{c'} \ln \lambda}\right)d\lambda \\
&\le 1 + \int_1^\infty P\left(|X| \ge \sqrt{\frac{1}{c'} \ln \lambda}\right)d\lambda \\
&\le 1 + C\int_1^\infty e^{-\frac{c}{c'} \ln \lambda} d\lambda \\
&= 1 + C \int_1^\infty \lambda^{-c/c'}d\lambda,
\end{align*}

so choose $c' < c$ and $C'$ to be the final line above.